# Validate PDF (X3) via PHP

Tags: php, validation, pdf

I've programmed an uploadscript for uploading PDF files. Via PHP I want to check if the uploaded files are ready for print using the X3 standard. That means images and fonts has to be embedded into the file etc.
Unfortunately I don't know how to achieve my aim? Does anybody has some ideas that might help me?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are referring to the ISO PDF/X-3 standard? Are you sure it has to be PDF/X-3 you need to check against? Most publishing workflows today use something based on either PDF/X-1a (the vast majority) or PDF/X-4 (up and coming).

How do you want the checking? There are a number of commercial libraries that allow you to PDF/X-3 checking (and other PDF preflight), do you want to use those or are you looking at implementing this yourself using some PHP library?

If you want to use an existing library, let me point you at [pdfToolbox](http://www.callassoftware.com/callas/doku.php/en%3aproducts%3apdftoolboxcli) from callas (*warning, I am affiliated with this company*) which has a command-line version that is easily usable from PHP (I made such an implementation with Drupal). There are definitely other companies that have technology in this area too, Enfocus comes to mind.

If you want to use a PHP PDF library to do this, be aware that PDF/X-3 checking goes much further than having all images and fonts embedded. There are a lot of very subtle requirements you'll have to implement.